# Is there any option to get firestore read usage based on users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

is there any option to get firestore read usage based on users

My APP or website needed to login before using so is there any way to get the firestore read right usage of each user?

Answer (score 0):

No, the only thing that's provided is what you see in the console - total read activity from all sources.  If you want to something more specific, you'll have to log it yourself somehow.